# Docker postgreSQL entrypoint-initdb.d choose database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - APP_DB_USER=docker
      - APP_DB_PASS=docker
      - APP_DB_NAME=docker
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

in the same directory there is a directory `db` with 1 file `init.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        last_login TIMESTAMP 
);

insert into accounts(username,password,email,created_on) values ('a','aaa','assdfdas',now())
```

when I run `docker-compose up` (if the db is empty) the `init.sql` file is executed but the database in which it is executed is `root` and not `postgres`, How can I change it?

[Imgur link to DataGrip screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY8E0.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the psql command `\connect <db-name>` inside your `init.sql` file in order to connect to the correct database (given that the database already exists).

In your case, the `init.sql` file would look something like:

```
\connect postgres   <-- connects to the 'postgres' database

CREATE TABLE accounts (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        last_login TIMESTAMP 
);
...
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried it with `\CONNECT` and apparently SQL is selectively case-sensitive

Comment: @Vulwsztyn you do not have to write it in uppercase as this is not usual SQL syntax but rather a psql command. Therefore, it should be sufficient to just write `\connect postgres` in order to connect (i.e. use) the `postgres` database.

Comment: do you happen to know how to tell vs code that it is correct syntax?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn unfortunately I do not know how to configure vscode to properly recognize the psql syntax. Anyway, I think you should compose a new question rather than abuse this thread for that matter.